# SSH - quoting error when composing command line with ProxyCommand (bash)

Tags: bash, ssh, shell, proxy, parameters

I would like to use the `ssh` command in a bash script running on `srcHost` to remotely execute a command on a range of hosts (`targetHostX`). Some of those remote hosts are only reachable via a jump host (`jumpHost`), while others can be reached directly from `srcHost`. SSH key auth is in place with the key `srcHost:~/id_rsa` being accepted for `usr@jumpHost` and `usr@targetHostX`, and the whole thing must work non-interactively, i.e. no password prompts. This means, I cannot use the `-J` (ProxyJump) option as it won't allow to specify an SSH key for the jump host.

The basic command line, confirmed working, would be this (example remote command: hostname):

`usr@srcHost:~$ ssh -i ~/id_rsa -o ProxyCommand="ssh -i ~/id_rsa -W %h:%p usr@jumpHost" usr@targetHostX hostname`

In my bash script, I have an associative array to define jump hosts for some targetHosts, and I would like to compose the SSH command line depending on whether a jump host is defined or not.
A bit simplified, it looks like this:

```
user="usr"
targethost="targetHostX"
remotecommand="hostname"
jumphost="${jumphosts[$targethost]}"
param=""

[ -n "$jumphost" ] && param="-o ProxyCommand=\"ssh -W $targethost:22 $jumphost\""

ssh $param -l $user $targethost "$remotecommand"
```

When I execute this (with `set -x` to see what's going on), I get:

```
+ '[' -n jumpHost ']'
+ param='-o ProxyCommand="ssh -W targetHostX:22 jumpHost"'
+ ssh -o 'ProxyCommand="ssh' -W targetHostX:22 'jumpHost"' -l usr targetHostX hostname
/bin/bash: -c: line 0: unexpected EOF while looking for matching `"'
/bin/bash: -c: line 1: syntax error: unexpected end of file
write: Broken pipe
```

I thought it must be some obscure quoting problem as is seemingly often the case with bash, and tried all kinds of different quoting styles including composing the command as an array - to no avail. As a workaround, I have now typed out two entire ssh command lines (the entire command line is longer than what is shown here as a minimal example) in two if branches, and this works but it is neither pretty nor well maintainable. Also, I want to understand what's going on.

Then I noticed, that the error only occurs with the `ssh` command! If I replace ssh with a little script that only echoes its command line, I get:

```
+ '[' -n jumpHost ']'
+ param='-o ProxyCommand="ssh -W targetHostX:22 jumpHost"'
+ ./command.sh -o 'ProxyCommand="ssh' -W targetHostX:22 'jumpHost"' -l usr targetHostX ''
Commandline: ./command.sh -o ProxyCommand="ssh -W targetHostX:22 jumpHost" -l usr targetHostX
```

No error, and the `./command.sh` is executed as expected.

I'm a bit stumped by this, has anybody on here an explanation for this problem? I assume I get the bash error from `jumpHost`, so maybe I have to change the quoting inside `ProxyCommand` - but how?

Thanks!

Comment: [How can we run a command stored in a variable?](https://unix.stackexchange.com/q/444946/108618) Your unquoted `$param` is exactly this. Use an array and quote right.

Comment: Yes, I found threads similar to this and tried quoting the ```$param``` but that gives me a different error:
```+ ssh '-o ProxyCommand="ssh -W targetHostX:22 jumpHost"' -l usr targetHostX hostname```
```/bin/bash: line 0: exec: ssh -W targetHostX:22 jumpHost: not found```

Also, that does not explain why it works when another shell script is invoked, but not when SSH is used. It's not a local bash problem, it must be related to SSH.

But I didn't encounter such a detailed explanation as in that thread yet, so thanks for the link.

Comment: (1) "Some of those remote hosts are only reachable via a jump host" -- Is there a reason for not defining `ProxyCommand` or so in your `~/.ssh/config`? You can configure for each host independently, using the `Host` keyword. The config is exactly for isolating such details, so any script can `ssh foo hostname` and doesn't need to worry if `foo` requires another key, a jump host or whatever. (2) "It won't allow to specify an SSH key for the jump host" -- I think this can also be in the config; specifically for the jump host, not the target host, so you can use this jump host straightforwardly.

Comment: That would be a good way forward, howevere in my case I don't want to change anything on ```srcHost``` besides my script, because it's a managed installation - so changing the users' SSH client config is not on the table. Also, I just want to understand what's the issue here...

Comment: OK. Still using a config file would be a neat way to manage things. You can do `ssh -F /path/to/myconfig ...` in the script. The config may `Include` other files (like `/etc/ssh/ssh_config` which is normally used, but here it will be suppressed by `-F`). Keep in mind the first obtained value for each parameter is used, so `Include /etc/ssh/ssh_config` should be at the end.

Comment: I didn't think of that, it's a good idea - thank you. Will try to do it that way.

Still, if there are any more ideas about the original question, I'd love to hear about it.

Answer (score 0):

#### Analysis

The problem is kinda because of wrong quoting, but you cannot really fix it by quoting better.

To understand what happens, let's first analyze the command that works:

> ```
> ssh -i ~/id_rsa -o ProxyCommand="ssh -i ~/id_rsa -W %h:%p usr@jumpHost" usr@targetHostX hostname
> ```

The shell splits it to words, expands the unquoted `~` and removes quotes. Finally `ssh` gets the following arguments:

- `-i`
- `/home/…/id_rsa`
- `-o`
- `ProxyCommand=ssh -i ~/id_rsa -W %h:%p usr@jumpHost`
- `usr@targetHostX`
- `hostname`

The double-quotes you used after `ProxyCommand=` vanished. `ssh` does not see the quotes. Their job was to tell the shell not to split your desired proxy command into separate words (they also prevented the second tilde). This is exactly right. After seeing `-o`, `ssh` expects `Option=value`, detects `ProxyCommand=` at the beginning of the next argument and uses the rest of the argument as the value, i.e. the proxy command.

However, in the script you have this:

> ```
> ssh $param …
> ```

(where `…` denotes arguments irrelevant to the issue). In general [you should double-quote variables](https://unix.stackexchange.com/a/131767/108618). I know why you didn't double-quote `$param`. You wanted `$param` to expand to multiple words. After this assignment:

> ```
> param="-o ProxyCommand=\"ssh -W $targethost:22 $jumphost\""
> ```

"Properly" quoted `$param` (i.e. `"$param"`) would expand to a single word being:

```
-o ProxyCommand="ssh -W …:22 …"
```

(where `…` denote what `$targethost` and `$jumphost` expanded to; note they expanded during assignment to `param`, not during expansion of `"$param"`). `ssh` would not understand it in the form of a single argument.

Your unquoted `$param` indeed expanded to multiple arguments; the first one being `-o` (so far so good), but then… These are the arguments:

- `-o`
- `ProxyCommand="ssh`
- `-W`
- `…:22` from the prior expansion of `$targethost:22`
- `…"` from the prior expansion of `$jumphost\"`
- trailing arguments irrelevant to the issue

In fact `set -x` has already given you the same list:

> ```
> + ssh -o 'ProxyCommand="ssh' -W targetHostX:22 'jumpHost"' -l usr targetHostX hostname
> ```

It uses single quotes when necessary to make its output unambiguous, but you need to pay attention and know how to interpret these single-quotes in the output. Here `-o` means `ssh` got `-o`, but `'ProxyCommand="ssh'` means `ssh` got `ProxyCommand="ssh`.

If the prior expansion of `$targethost` or `$jumphost` brought spaces, tabs or newlines into `param`, one or both arguments on the above list where I used `…` would in fact be multiple arguments.

I guess you embedded double-quotes into the value of `$param` to protect some part of it from being split upon unquoted `$param`. This doesn't work. Quotes inside variables are not special to the shell. Not only your embedded quotes failed to prevent splitting; they did not disappear. `ssh` saw `-o`, expected `Option=value`, got `ProxyCommand="ssh`. What it got looks like `Option=value`, so `ssh` itself did not complain. Still, when it tried to run the `value` as shell code by passing it to `/bin/bash -c`, the actual value was literally:

```
"ssh
```

and this isn't valid as shell code. Hence the error:

> ```
> /bin/bash: -c: line 0: unexpected EOF while looking for matching `"'
> ```

---

#### Solution

You could use e.g. `IFS=#` to make the shell split unquoted `$param` exactly where you want; plus `set -o noglob` just in case. Or you could use `eval "ssh $param …"` and re-evaluate the expansion of `ssh $param …`, so quotes embedded inside `$param` would become special at some point. Each workaround requires you to carefully craft the value of `$param` and the accompanying shell code and variables; each may work if the code and the values are static and if you know what you're doing. OTOH if one is familiar enough with Bash to know what he or she would be doing with `IFS` or `eval` here, then one probably knows the right way.

The right way is to use an array. Even in `sh` there is `"$@"` that behaves like an array. Your question is tagged [bash](/questions/tagged/bash) and you already used an array in your code (`"${jumphosts[$targethost]}"`, an associative array), so you surely can use another one. The name may be `param`.

<sup>(More here: [How can we run a command stored in a variable?](https://unix.stackexchange.com/q/444946/108618))</sup>

Your code fixed:

```bash
user="usr"
targethost="targetHostX"
remotecommand="hostname"
jumphost="${jumphosts[$targethost]}"
param=()

[ -n "$jumphost" ] && param=(-o "ProxyCommand=ssh -W $targethost:22 $jumphost")

ssh "${param[@]}" -l "$user" "$targethost" "$remotecommand"
```

`param=()` defines an empty array. If the array stays empty then `"${param[@]}"` will expand to zero words. The whole thing will work as you expect…

… unless `$targethost` or `$jumphost` is unfortunate or not totally under your control. When `ssh` passes the value of `ProxyCommand=` to `/bin/bash -c`, the already expanded `$targethost` and `$jumphost` will be just substrings of the string interpreted as shell code. E.g. if an attacker manages to make `"${jumphosts[$targethost]}"` expand to `; rm -f /important/file;` then your proxy command will execute `rm -f /important/file`. If this is a concern, consider:

```
[ -n "$jumphost" ] && param=(-o "ProxyCommand=ssh -W ${targethost@Q}:22 ${jumphost@Q}")
```

Bash interpreting the script will substitute `${targethost@Q}` and `${jumphost@Q}` with the respective values quoted or escaped if needed. In effect when the whole string is interpreted as shell code (by `/bin/bash -c` invoked by `ssh`), whatever comes from the variables cannot inject code.

---

#### What about `echo`

> Then I noticed, that the error only occurs with the `ssh` command! If I replace ssh with a little script that only echoes its command line, I get [no error.]"

`echo` is not a good tool for such debugging, as it accepts anything and it doesn't really tell you what exact arguments it got. It concatenates its arguments, inserting spaces in between. From the output you cannot tell which space comes from some argument and which comes from `echo`. E.g. all these commands will print the same output:

```
echo -o ProxyCommand=ssh … 
echo -o "ProxyCommand=ssh …"
echo "-o ProxyCommand=ssh …"
```

But if you replace `echo` with `ssh` then obviously the resulting commands will not be equivalent.

Personally I use `printf '<%s>\n'`. Try these one by one:

```
printf '<%s>\n' -o ProxyCommand=ssh … 
printf '<%s>\n' -o "ProxyCommand=ssh …"
printf '<%s>\n' "-o ProxyCommand=ssh …"
```

An argument containing `>(zero or more spaces or tabs)(newline)<` or a carriage return character (or an escape sequence my terminal will interpret, or …) can still fool me, nevertheless this method is way better than `echo`.